# how to disable msr in virt-manager on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: xubuntu, virtualization, virt-manager

I'm trying To passthrough ethernet adaptor, i enabled immmou, when i boot the virtual machine it give me this

```
`Error starting domain: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-08-18T07:34:45.401121Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.401272Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.404086Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.404171Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.476073Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:00:19.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,rombar=0: vfio 0000:00:19.0: failed to setup container for group 2: Failed to set iommu for container: Operation not permitted

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1279, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-08-18T07:34:45.401121Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.401272Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.404086Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.404171Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-08-18T07:34:45.476073Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:00:19.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,rombar=0: vfio 0000:00:19.0: failed to setup container for group 2: Failed to set iommu for container: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: i tried kvm.ignore_msrs=1

Comment: The MSR/vmx related warnings are NOT your problem. They just report a mismatch of what qemu expects from your CPU to what it can run (subfeatures to vmx). These are just warnings and in this case a red herring. Your actual issue is "Failed to set iommu for container: Operation not permitted" so maybe you'd want to rephrase the question.

Comment: If you switch from a named CPU qemu has some expectations to a different one or host-passthrough those are likely to vanish, but your vfio/iommu issue will stay.